# Use matrix algebra to show $A(B^{-1}(A+B)A^{-1})B = A+B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got a super simple linear algebra question for an intro college course I can't seem to figure out.

> Using matrix algebra and matrix identities, show that:
>   $$
> A(B^{-1}(A+B)A^{-1})B = A+B
> $$

I'm figuring that I have to somehow cancel the left and right expressions. I know that $AA^{-1} = I$.

However in this question I have two different matrices. How can I cancel them out?

Comment: Just split it up and multiply it out. It will just fall out...

Answer (score 6):

$A(B^{-1}(A+B)A^{-1})B= AB^{-1}(AA^{-1})B+A(B^{-1}B)A^{-1}B=A(B^{-1}B)+(AA^{-1})B=A+B$